# Prevent AirPods from opening Mac's Music (iTunes) app?

Tags: iphone, itunes, mac, music, airpods

How do I prevent my AirPods Pro from launching my Mac's Music App (formerly iTunes) when I squeeze the stem to play?

I wear my AirPods Pro pretty much all day and I'm constantly switching between my  my Mac and my iPhone. If I put the Mac to sleep, and then, forgetting that I'm still connected to my Mac, squeeze the stem to play something on my iPhone, the Music app will launch on my Mac.

I understand what's happening here and I get why it's programmed that way… *and* I totally understand that it's my fault for forgetting that I'm connected to my Mac and not my iPhone… but it's still annoying. How do I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's currently a way to disable this.

---

Squeezing the stem triggers "play" on the device it's connected to, and as of now there is no way to alter this behavior.

Therefore the only solution is to disable "play" from opening Music on your Mac. Unfortunately, [solutions to this](https://superuser.com/q/31925/510452) no longer work with the current version of MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

I installed [noTunes](https://github.com/tombonez/noTunes) on MacOS 12.6.1 using the Homebrew method. noTunes adds an icon (that looks similar to the Music.app icon) to your top menu bar. Clicking on it toggles between allowing Music to launch when ending a call or removing your AirPods. When the icon looks like the Music icon with a circle with crossbar (i.e., the No symbol), then it prevents Music from launching when ending a call or removing your AirPods.

If you do not use Homebrew, the linked page also has a downloadable .zip file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).